# Position of a view with .zero frame

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view (VIEW A). I need to get it's position inside of it's superview (ideally a CGPoint for it's Center X and Center Y).

This would be easy, except that when I add VIEW A into the view, I set it's frame to be .zero, and use  NSLayoutConstraint anchors to position it. So later, when I want to get it's frame (I've also tried it's bounds), it comes back as (0,0,0,0).

VIEW A is visible and positioned inside it's superview...so it has some X/Y coordinates and width/height right? How do I access these values?

Comment: We need to see your code in order to tell what's going on. My guess is that you're adding constraints but not giving the constraint time to move/size your view before you get it's frame. (Are you calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the parent view?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `setNeedsLayout()` **AND** `layoutIfNeeded()` on the parent view:

```
let myView = UIView(frame: .zero)
myView.backgroundColor = .red
myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

view.addSubview(myView)
myView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingBelow(view.topAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
myView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(view.leftAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true

view.setNeedsLayout()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
print(myView.frame)
```

Comment: For whatever reason, it was only layoutIfNeeded() that was needed here. Solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Apple must have improved the Auto Layout engine to mark the parent view as needing layout already. Old habits die hard.

Answer (score 2):

A safe place to get access to updated frames is on viewDidLayoutSubviews after the call to super's implementation

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    // Here we have access to updated frames
}
```

If you are adding the subview, say, in viewDidLoad, then the UIViewController hasn't make any calculation for the frames. It just has the rules (constraints) describing the relations between its views. In the lifecycle of a UIViewController, viewDidLayoutSubviews is the point where the frame calculations has already been done and it's safe to access them. You can even calculate some frames yourself after the super call.

Comment: The subview is getting added after the superview is already laid out so I don't think I can utilize it here. That said, this is useful context and something I didn't know, so thank you!

Comment: Not a bad place to get frame of the subviews, but with 2 caveats: (1) you do not know when it is called (technically the next update cycle from the run loop); and (2) only the child views' bounds are known. No guarantee about the grand children views.